# how to use java jnr to infer a clib struct

Tags: java, jnr, clib

Is there a way for jnr to construct a struct for me in order to access a returned call using jnr.

for example, if I wanted to use

```
int statvfs(const char *path, struct statvfs *buf);
```

where struct statvfs is:

```
struct statvfs {
    unsigned long  f_bsize;    /* file system block size */
    unsigned long  f_frsize;   /* fragment size */
    fsblkcnt_t     f_blocks;   /* size of fs in f_frsize units */
    fsblkcnt_t     f_bfree;    /* # free blocks */
    fsblkcnt_t     f_bavail;   /* # free blocks for unprivileged users */
    fsfilcnt_t     f_files;    /* # inodes */
    fsfilcnt_t     f_ffree;    /* # free inodes */
    fsfilcnt_t     f_favail;   /* # free inodes for unprivileged users */
    unsigned long  f_fsid;     /* file system ID */
    unsigned long  f_flag;     /* mount flags */
    unsigned long  f_namemax;  /* maximum filename length */
};
```

how would I be able to access this?

Answer (score 1):

To use C++ struct, you should define class that extends `jnr.ffi.Struct` . Each field should have one of the java-types, defined in `jnr.ffi.Struct` class or extended from one of it.

For example `short` field from *.h file should be defined as `jnr.ffi.Struct.Signed16` in struct class.

If you need to have an array field, you **must** initialize it using static method `Struct.array(Struct.Signed8[] array)` as following:

```java
public final Signed8[] byteArray = array(new Signed8[8])
```

Comment: you mean pointer as field of struct or want to know usage of `Pointer` class?